# Discovering anti debugging strategy used by a program

Tags: debugging, assembly, malware

Try to find the anti-debugging behaviour in a malicious program 
The following is a piece of function from a malicious program which uses anti-debugging
techniques. I am unable to figure out what anti-debugging techniques it may be using.

**My thoughts :** 
I see the lines

```
move dl, 0CCh
mov eax, offset _main
```

and then it compares

```
 cmp [eax],  dl
```

If they are equal it calls **theend** which ends the program 
Seems it's doing something here but not sure.

[image]

Comment: Yes, a software breakpoint instruction `int3` has opcode `0xCC`. The code is checking if a debugger put such a breakpoint in `main` overwriting whatever the original code is there.

Comment: The `continueloop` bit implements a loop back to the comparison to check if any of the bytes from `_main` up to below `blocEnd` are equal to 0CCh, which is the single-byte `int3` instruction's opcode.

Answer (score 1):

0xCC is the opcode of [INT 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)) instruction. When you put a breakpoint (We are talking about software breakpoints here) on an assembly instruction, the debugger changes the first byte of the instruction opcode to 0xCC and the code execution will break at that point.

An anti-debug technique you mentioned is trying to detect if any byte of the _main block has been changed to 0xCC or not and if that's the case, it can easily detect it by a simple comparison.

However, you still need to debug the code and need to use breakpoints to analyze the code and the solution here is to use hardware breakpoints.

A little search on google shows some results like [this one](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/367-anti-reverse-engineering-protection-techniques-to-use-before-releasing-software) which explains the differences and the techniques to detect each of them.

Comment: So whenever a breakpoint is set. The debugger actually modifies the code ?